# What are "Factor Graphs" and what are they useful for?

Tags: statistics, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

A friend is using Factor Graphs to do text mining (identifying references to people in text), and it got me interested in this tool, but I'm having a hard time finding an intuitive explanation of what Factor Graphs are and how to use them.

Can anyone provide an explanation of Factor Graphs that isn't math heavy, and which focusses on practical applications rather than abstract theory?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are used extensively for breaking down a problem into pieces. One very interesting application of factor graphs (and message passing on them) is the XBox Live TrueSkill algorithm. I [wrote extensively about it](http://www.moserware.com/2010/03/computing-your-skill.html) on my blog where I tried to go for an introductory explanation rather than an overly academic one.

Comment: Just a side comment, but that was an awesome blog post.

Comment: Ah Jeff, yes - I actually read your blog post a few months ago, ok - to be honest I got  about half way through it.  But I'm using the Java version of your software for a [side project](http://rank.my/) of mine.  I didn't actually realize that factor graphs were used for TrueSkill, I need to go back and read your blog entry in its entirety.

Answer (score 4):

A factor graph is the graphical representation of the dependencies between variables and factors (parts of a formula) that are present in a particular kind of formula.

Suppose you have a function `f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)` and you want to compute the marginalization of this function for some argument `x_i`, thus summing over all assignments to the remaining formula. Further `f` can be broken into factors, e.g.

`f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=f_1(x_1,x_2)f_2(x_5,x_8,x_9)...f_k(x_1,x_10,x_11)`

Then in order to compute the marginalization of `f` for some of the variables you can use a special algorithm called sum product (or message passing), that breaks the problem into smaller computations. For this algortithm, it is very important which variables appear as arguments to which factor. This information is captured by the factor graph.

A **factor graph** is a bipartite graph with both factor nodes and variable nodes. And there is an edge between a factor and a variable node if the variable appears as an argument of the factor. In our example there would be an edge between the factor `f_2` and the variable `x_5` but not between `f_2` and `x_1`.

There is a great article: [Factor graphs and the sum-product algorithm](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=15860566791198058138).

Answer (score 4):

Factor graph is math model, and can be explained only with math equations. In nutshell it is way to explain complex relations between interest variables in your model. Example: A is temperature, B is pressure, components C,D,E are depends on B,A in some way, and component K is depends on B,A. And you want to predict value K based on A and B. So you know only visible states. Basic ML libraries don't allow to model such structure. Neural network do it better. And Factor Graph is exactly solve that problem.
Factor graph is an example of deep learning. When it is impossible to  present model with features and output, Factor models allow to build hidden states, layers and complex structure of variables to fit real world behavior. Examples are  Machine translation alignment, fingerprint recognition, co-reference etc.